# Set up QT creator for raspberry

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

I finally compiled QT 5.7.0 for raspberry pi 3 i have succeed in compilation and running one of the example on PI. Now i am just trying to set up QT creator 4.2.1 for development but it says error in step qmake. I am sure that I set everything right but for unknown reason it does not work

For compilation and set up QT creator i have followed these two manuals

https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-raspberry-pi

https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

This is the compile error:

Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Raspberry)
When executing step "qmake"

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

As you use the tag "cross-compiling" for you question. I assume that you build your software on your desktop (host) with a toolchain and run it after on the raspberry (target).

It's may be an error with your kit creation on Qt Creator.

You can check the step by step video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1d2bh7iUKNc to "configure Qt Creator to cross-compile Raspberry Pi 3 application from your computer and remotely run it"

All the steps are covered from the kit creation to the remote debugging.

EDIT: Take a look at 2:02, you can add the a "raspberry pi qmake" to Qt Creator. Go to: Tools | Options | Build & Run | Qt version | Add. You must use a "raspberry pi qmake" to cross-compile your project, not your regular "desktop qmake".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks fot the tip. I updated my answer with the process to add a "raspberry pi qmake" to Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

1) Since you are using RPi3 device be advised to consider Qt5.8 and [RaspberryPi Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) [02.03.2017 release].
In addition, you can find nice video tutorial on [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_uOybXbDYI]

2) Second option is to use [Arch Linux for Rpi3](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) which has all newest Qt5 builds.